# blank Toolbar from setItems

Tags: ios, uitoolbar

My UINavigationController toolbar is blank and no items show up on it. Here is my code

```
self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;

UIToolbar* toolbar = self.navigationController.toolbar;
NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[items addObject:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Test"
                                                  style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                 target:self
                                                 action:@selector(buttonPushed)]];
[toolbar setItems:items animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the proper way to setup the toolbar. `UIViewController` has a `toolbarItems` property. The nav controller will use that property to automatically populate its toolbar.

Your code should be:

```
self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;

UIBarButtonItem *btnTest = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Test"
                                              style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                             target:self
                                             action:@selector(buttonPushed)]];
self.toolbarItems = @[ btnTest ];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked for me. How would I extend it to add an arbitrary number of buttons?